# How can we integrate dynamic-feature module in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I have a project in android and wanted to integrate the Cordova module using [dynamic-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand), I am able to integrate the module in Cordova via a simple library integration, but when I did the setup for dynamic-delivery it gives me the below error

> `* What went wrong:` 
>  `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.`
>  `Unable to find matching projects for Dynamic Features: [:featureName]`

To resolve the error, I tried to follow the library integration step with my tweak and understanding which is as below,

- At first, I understand the problem that it fails to find the dynamic-feature module.
- So went back to library integration
- In `project.properties` I have added `android.library.reference.1 = libraryName` (you can assume that I have followed remaining steps to integrate library)
- So to remove the library from a project I have removed the code that adds a library, if I don't follow this step then Cordova automatically adds implementation code (and gives circular dependency error) in the app's Gradle and it assumes that we wanted to add a library, after following this step android no longer adds library implementation code.
- Till this step, I have assumed that if I can add the library by adding code `android.library.reference` then I should be able to add the dynamic feature by `android.dynamic-feature.reference`,
- I have come to the above conclusion on the basis of the observation of `build.gradle` for ex. if you want to add a library in android you modify the plugin line with `apply plugin: com.android.library`.
- Anyway, my result is a failure and I am not able to figure out how we can add dynamic-feature in Cordova, if anyone can guide me with documentation, tutorial or small help in whatever little steps I followed will be very helpful.

P.S. I have used and integrated dynamic-feature in native android and with unity library successfully, so you can assume that I followed all steps correctly, it's just that in Cordova I am able to not bridge this integration.

Comment: it'd called a plugin

Comment: I know that if you want to add any feature in Cordova, you need to add the plugin. But I am unsure how to write that plugin code or don't have any idea of any documentation or tutorial to do so; I hope I understand you correctly. if you can guide me on how to write dynamic-feature plugin in cordova, it will be very helpful.